# What makes a function also be a combinator?

Tags: functional-programming

Can somebody clarify what a combinator is? What does a function need to also be a combinator? Is there a formal definition? Going through the Functional Programming in Scala book, and both terms seem to be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conventionally, functions represent modules of your program.  Combinators, on the other hand, don't really represent modules in the same sense; instead, they are used to combine modules into a whole program.

A combinator 'combines' two (or more) values, in such a way that the arguments are 'part of' the result.  A heuristic for recognizing combinators is that they take at least one argument with the same (or a similar) type as their own result.[1]  So, for example, `many` (pseudo-Haskell):

```
many :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
```

is a combinator, because it takes a parser and returns a parser, and because the parser `p` is a part of the parser `many p`.

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

is not a combinator, both because it takes a list but returns an `Int`, and because it discards most of the information from its argument.

```
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

is also not a combinator, becase while it takes `Int`s and returns an `Int`, it still discards part of the information from its arguments; `2` and `3` aren't really 'part of' `5` in the same way `p` is a part of `many p`.

The intuition is that when you're writing your program, you start by structuring it into pieces: parse the first bit of the input, parse this repeated element, parse the rest, put the parse trees together.  You code those pieces, then apply combinators to them to get the final program:

```
putThePiecesTogether <$> parseTheFirstBit <*> many parseRepeatedBit <*> parseTheRest
```

[1] Combinators come from combinator libraries, which will also have '0-argument' combinators (constants or just functions of other types).  Those are also important parts of the library and are probably combinators in their own right, so the real rule is that a combinator comes from a library most of whose functions both take and return values of the same type, in such a way that the arguments are 'part of' the result.